# How are the operators in Java able to work with different data types?

Tags: java

How are operators in Java able to work with different data types? I thought operators in Java are not overloaded, so how is it possible to work with different data types then.

For example,

```
Integer ex; 
ex != null;
```

How am I able to just use != operator with a null reference value, which can be of any type, with a variable of ex Integer type, are not both of the types different in this case? The same question can be asked about = operator.

Just like that then:

How is it possible to use the + operator with two different data types of int and double like this:

```
int x = 9; 
double z = 11.5; 
z = x + z;
```

Is it just defined in the Java language for the operators to work with any data types like this, or is there a concept I am missing because I thought we could not overload operators to use them for any data type and manipulate their purpose. Also, would operators count as methods if we overload methods and we are talking about overloading operators?

Comment: That's two different questions, the first is about auto-boxing (JLS [5.1.7. Boxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) and [5.1.8. Unboxing Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) and compound assignment operators (JLS [15.26.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)), and the second is about numeric promotions (JLS [5.6. Numeric Contexts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6)). Please only ask one question per question.

Comment: *"How am I able to just use != operator"* You're not, since there is no such operator in Java.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought operators in Java are not overloaded, so how is it possible to work with different data types then.

Java operators are overloaded.

What Java does not support is **user defined** operator overloading.

> Is it just defined in the Java language for the operators to work with any data types like this ...

The Java Language Specification (JLS) defines which Java operators can be used with which types ... and precisely what they mean.  This is specified in Sections 15.14 through 15.26 of [JLS Chapter 15](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html).

---

> Also, would operators count as methods if we overload methods and we are talking about overloading operators?

Erm ... no.  Operators are not methods<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - I don't follow the logic of your argument.   This is a bit like asking "Do cows count as cars since I can drive both cars and cattle?".</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have *user defined* operator overloading: you can't define custom behavior for the operators. That doesn't mean there isn't any operator overloading. The `+` operator for example is overloaded for numerical types and strings.

> How am I able to just use != operator with a null reference value, which can be of any type

The type of the null reference is [the special "null type"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) which is a subtype of all other reference types. In particular, it's a subtype of Integer, so the comparison between Integer and null is valid.

> How is it possible to use the + operator with two different data types of int and double

There's is an implicit conversion of the int value to double. You're using the version of the + operator that is defined on two double values.

This implicit conversion [only happens in a "numeric context"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6):

"If any expression is of type double, then the promoted type is double, and other expressions that are not of type double undergo widening primitive conversion to double."